# Athena table data different from file in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Hi I have a File X1 (1 sheet) sitting in S3. I have created a table on Athena using File X1. When I review the records in this table, I noticed that from my fourth column, the results (from row 2 onwards) are all shifted by one column. But the headers are all correct.

For context, the S3 files gets updated with new rows via github (this is done by another team). When I go to S3 to look at the file, everything is all in order. I do not know why when the data is passed into Athena, it would be shifted.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: The parsing of the file might be confused based on the SERDE you use. You might have commas in text fields or other characters that are mixing the columns.

Comment: I have faced a similar issue, the root cause in my case was a mismatch of the datatype I was using for a few fields, please verify the datatype of each field.